# what is the maximum cpu usage I can get on a core i7

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a core i7 laptop. I just know this architecture is quadcore hyperthread which makes the user think the box has 8 cores.

Since I have no idea what the above line means :) I am asking:

1. what is the max cpu usage my multithreaded program, in
   theory, can get on this laptop? is it 400% or 800% ?
2. when I execute `make -j 6` does this mean I am compiling the
   application on 6 threads over 6 cores? but i only have 4 cores!
3. can I run `make -j 10` on this machine? Actually I did, but the OS
   almost hanged

Anyways, my application, upon compilation or runtime, never got a cpu usage over 370% (this is what `top` command says)

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to answer your questions:

1. There are i7 processors with 2 or 4 "real cores", as can be seen here: http://ark.intel.com/products/family/75023/4th-Generation-Intel-Core-i7-Processors/mobile#@All
   If you look up your praticular model of processor in that list, how many "real" cores it has, and assuming HT is enabled in your settings (BIOS settings or similar), you can multiply that number by 2. The OS will assume that HT * cores is the number of actual processing units, and give statistics based on that. In other words, if you have 4 real cores and HT enabled, you should be able to achieve 800% CPU usage. 
   or you could use `cat /proc/cpuinfo |grep -c vendor_id` to get a count of actual cores that the OS sees (assuming Linux, but since you use top, that seems plausible).
2. It will run 6 jobs = processes, not threads. How many threads will depend on exactly what your makefile actually does. And of course, these jobs will be distributed as best as the OS can achieve over your available CPU resources (cores * (HT?2:1)).
3. In theory, sure. But if you want the machine to be responsive, running 10 CPU-hungry jobs (e.g. compilation) on a machine with 4 or 8 (cores * (HT?2:1)) will potentially use up all CPU resources, and if the compilation is of fairly large sources, you may find that the total memory used by the compilation processes uses more memory than is physically available in your machine, leading to excessive swapping, and not actually achieving better results. Ideal is to have all cores busy, but enough memory available to avoid swapping.

If your compile job gets 370%, then you are either running out of memory (swapping causing disk IO) or your source code is large enough that the OS can't read the files quick enough to keep up with the compiler. If it's "waiting for disk I/O", running a higher number of jobs can help. If it's running out of memory, running a lower number will be better (as that reduces the memory pressure). We can't really say which of those two scenarios. You can check "Mem" and "Swap" in top to see what's going on there.

Comment: I've seen quite a few programs compile faster with more than N processes (N being the number cores) being used for compilation though, I'd say somewhere between N and 2N is usually optimal. Assuming we don't run out of memory (memory is cheap these days, get more!) at least.

Comment: Memory is indeed not very expensive, but laptops often come with much smaller memory than desktops, e.g. 4GB that mine has is most likely not enough to run 10 compiles of something complex, where my desktop at home and at work has 16GB, and "can take it" from a memory perspective.

Answer (score 3):

Technically, the most you can get is 100% :-)

But, I assume (since you mention `top`) that you are on linux (you should tag the question so), which does tot each CPU load up to provide a max val of 100% * n (for n logical CPU).

I cant recall exactly how it treats hyperthreading - it might scale up to 400% or 800%. And it probably depends if you have hyperthreading enabled in bios.

With regards to make: `make -j n` asks make to run upto 6 jobs at a time. This might be 6 calls to gcc, other make commands, whatever the makefile contains. It wont always be able to run that number, it depends how well the makefile is constructed to allow parallel builds, and you can write chapters on that. Those 6 jobs may run on 6 seperate cores, on the same core, or a mixture. It all depends where the scheduler puts them, and they will probably move cores through execution anyway.

The reason you dont get number-of-jobs*100 % usage, is because builds are very rarely CPU bound. There is a lot of disk IO. Reading makefiles, scanning dependencys, reading source and all the included files, writing the output file, writing dependency files etc all contribute significantly to the build time, and while the process is waiting for these operations, they will be idle.

Can you run `make -j 10`. Yes, you could pick any number. It is normally recommended to set to the number of CPUs you have, i personally prefer to run a few more than that, but really it depends on what the make is doing. If the machine becomes unresponsive at -10, dont do it!

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I had a homework assignment to test the compilation speed of `make` with different numbers of jobs on Intel Core I7-3770K @ 3.5GHz 64Bit with HT with an SSD and 16GB RAM on FreeBSD 9.1 using gcc 4.6.1.. Here are the results:
[image]
The bottom axis is the number of jobs. The left axis is the speedup compared to `-j 1`.
The green line is Boost 1.54.0, the blue line is Dosbox 0.7.4. All measurements were made 10 times in a row.

Answer (score 1):

This is my experience on sparc machines (e.g. Oracle/Sun's Netra T5440 that had 8 cores, with up to 128 hardware threads).

One thing is what the OS thinks it has. for example, if I run mpstat it will happily report:

```
 CPU minf mjf xcal  intr ithr  csw icsw migr smtx  srw syscl  usr sys  wt idl
   0  157   0  537   193   28  424    2   30   11    0  1368    7   5   0  88
   1    9   0  250   236   79  260    2   23    6    0   647    8   2   0  90
   ...
 125    1   0   51    47   15   49    0    4    2    0   131    3   0   0  97
 126    1   0   49    47   15   49    0    4    2    0   132    3   0   0  97
 127    2   0   81    90   32   96    1    7    3    0   238    6   1   0  93
```

i.e. it has 128 processing resources... and the OS will do the scheduling based on the availability of 128 processing resources. This means that every second it has 128000 ms. of CPU time available (which sometimes can be expressed as a max CPU usage of 12800%)

However. These 128 *fake* CPU resources are built into 8 hardware cores. This means that there are hardware resources, pipes, buses... **shared** and those are potential contention points. This means that when you drive them hard, actual throughput will be affected when you go over 70%-80% CPU usage (per-thread).

Now, processes in OS can use one or more *OS threads*. But this is a different concept (although related) than the hardware threads or CPU hyperthreads.

The OS handles heavy processes with associated memory and with one or more light processes (unit of scheduling) or threads. Multiple OS threads share the same process memory.

In general, the scheduling means that at any time, only one scheduling unit can be active in a given processing resource. This means one thread can use up to 1000 ms of CPU time per second [100%]. The same applies to a single-thread process, while a multithreaded process can use up to N*1000ms of CPU time per second [N*100%].

From previous is clear that the number of (active) threads in your system should remain below or equal the number of CPU resources. Then you need to factor in concepts that you must allow for some CPU power to still be available to do some house keeping or background tasks (e.g. running a shell to be able to enter a look at what's going on or the many background OS processes).... and also you must factor in that your hyperthreading multicore thingy will not be able to give its full 100% per cpu resource because of the hardware contention we discussed above.

If the number of threads is greater than the CPU resources available, then they will be unable to run, waiting for the scheduler to grant them a CPU resource and incurring in the cost of switching context and the like.

When you run `make -j 6`, you're instructing `make` to start at most 6 tasks at a time (given the dependency constraints), each of those tasks will be an OS process, which might be single-threaded (typically compilers are). If we assume all the processes are single threaded means that you would be using a maximum of 6 of the 8 cores (different ones at any time)

When you run `make -j 10`, you're instructing make to start at most 10 tasks. From my previous explanation you can figure out what can happen. Assuming single-threaded processes, it means that you have 10 threads (+ the rest of the operating processes) competing for 8 CPU resources...